# Eclipse ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Environment

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

I'm trying to lunch an application from Eclipse CDT and as I read everywhere, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory containing the shared library:

[image]

However, when I try to run this configuration:

```
/home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/make/CloudCache: error while loading shared libraries: libvl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Just to clarify: I'm 100% sure that `libvl.so` is in that path, in fact when I try to run the application from command line it works perfectly.

Why this happens?

Comment: have you figured out the solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue, I will be thankful if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is being reset somewhere else.  You can also set environment variable in the Launch Configuration if you are using that.  There are two places in there, one where you have an 'Environment' tab, and another where you choose your 'Build Configuration' which could itself point somewhere else.

I've just been trying to get this to work for the first time in eclipse (Linux 64), and did exactly what you showed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but still can be useful. You have the option "Append environment to native environment" checked on your screenshot. Very probably you have this variable redefined there. It was my case.